# Sequential processing algorithms/Patterns - Azure service bus queue

Tags: azure, message-queue, sequence

We are using azure service bus queues for posting messages.
We are pushing message in queue using async functions so that we get maximum throughput.

Later these messages can be picked up by worker role for processing it.
We would require strict order of processing messages. But, since we pushed messages async into queue, there is no order followed in queue.

I would require some sort of algorithm/design pattern which allow us to:

1. Do sequential processing of messages even if there are not in order inside queue.
2. it should allow us to push messages in queue asynchronously, i.e. not sacrificing queue throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alan Smith has some great blog posts on patterns for the Service Bus, sounds like you need the resquencer pattern: http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2012/03/23/149093.aspx

Also take a look at his other posts for other patterns.

Stephen Kaufman also has some nice blog posts on this too (along with the other patterns): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/skaufman/archive/2012/04/16/integration-patterns-utilizing-the-windows-azure-service-bus-part-ii.aspx

HTH

Comment: Resequence looks practical and promising for achieving high throughput. Thanks for sharing links.